# Range of $e^{\sqrt{y-x-x^2}}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

What is the range of $e^{\sqrt{y-x-x^2}}$? $range=(0,\infty)?$

Answer (score 0):

$\sqrt{y-x-x^2}$ has range $(0,\infty)$ whenever it is defined (assuming we restrict domain to have positive $y-x-x^2$).

Therefore the range of $\exp(y-x-x^2)$ is $[1,\infty)$, as $\exp(0) = 1$.